# If my iphone app use Dropbox SDK , must be a user has an account in Dropbox

Tags: iphone, xcode, dropbox

I develop iphone app use Dropbox SDK to load image from my Dropbox account, 
 I want to know must be a user has an account in Dropbox for use my app

Answer (score 0):

When the Dropbox SDK takes the user to either the Dropbox app or the browser for login purposes, then it also shows the user a 'sign up' link/button to take care of case in which user does not have an account already.

Regardless, it depends on whether your app is just a Dropbox client and can be useful without user logging into Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't need an account, set it up in a public location on dropbox;

https://www.dropbox.com/help/140/en

> "Everything in your Public folder is accessible to anyone online"